# query with buffer

Tags: qgis, spatial-query

I have 2 points layers. One contains old address points and the second has new address points. They don't have any unique attribute with which I could join them.

So, I've made a 10 metre buffer around the new points to find the old ones close to them (they have similar coordinates) and now I have to check if the new addresses are correct.

Is there any way that I can make a query which will check if the given addresses in the buffer around the new address points is the same as the given address in the old points?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use 'Vector  >  Data Management Tools  >  Joins Attributes by location'.  As the buffer was created from the new address layer, the attributes will be in the buffer.  This tool will join the new address attributes to those old address points that fall within the buffer.  WARNING this will only work effectively if a single old address point falls within the buffer, else you'll find you'll have multiple points with the same joined attributes and could get confusing.  From there it's a simple select query that one column matches the other.